# Openlayers 6.3.1 - rendering tilelayers

Tags: performance, rendering, openlayers, openlayers-6

In Openlayers 6 each layer has an independent renderer (previously, all layer rendering was managed by a single map renderer and depended on a single rendering strategy - https://openlayers.org/workshop/en/webgl/meteorites.html). In my project I have more then 20 TileLayers (TileWMS), and the loading, panning, scrolling performance worse then in openlayers 5. Can I set the rendering strategy? How can I increase performance?

The tiles are loading fast, but then (after loading tiles) panning on map is slow. The GPU usage not critical (below 30%)

Angular 9 project, logic in service classes:

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EMap {

    private eMap: OlMap;
    
    public createMapObject(): void {
        this.eMap = new OlMap({
            layers: [],
            view: new View({
                projection,
                resolutions: resolutionsArray,
                constrainResolution: true,
                enableRotation: false
            }),
            controls: defaultControls({
                rotate: false,
                attribution: false,
                zoom: false
            }).extend([
                mousePositionControl,
                scalelineControl
            ])
        });
    }
    
    public initMap(center: Coordinate, zoom: number, target: string): void {
        this.eMap.getView().setCenter(center);
        this.eMap.getView().setZoom(zoom);
        this.eMap.setTarget(target);
    }

    public addLayer(layer: TileLayer | ImageLayer | VectorLayer): void {
        this.eMap.addLayer(layer);
    }
}

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EMapSupportlayers extends EMapNetworklayers {

    constructor(private readonly eMap: EMap) {}
    
    public addTilelayer(networklayerInfo: NetworklayerInfo): void {

        const layer: TileLayer = this.createTileLayer(tileLayerInitValues);
        this.eMap.addLayer(layer);
    }

    private createTileLayer(tileLayerInitValues: TileLayerInitValues): TileLayer {      
        const tileGrid: TileGrid = new TileGrid({
                extent: tileLayerInitValues.tileGridExtent,
                resolutions: tileLayerInitValues.resolutions,
                tileSize: tileLayerInitValues.tileSize
            });

        const source = new TileWMS({
            url: tileLayerInitValues.url,
            params: {
                LAYERS: tileLayerInitValues.layerName,
                FORMAT: tileLayerInitValues.layerFormat
            },
            tileLoadFunction: (image: any, src: string) => this.customLoader(image, src),
            tileGrid
        });

        return new TileLayer({
            visible: tileLayerInitValues.visible,
            maxZoom: tileLayerInitValues.maxZoom,
            minZoom: ttileLayerInitValues.minZoom,
            source,
            zIndex: tileLayerInitValues.zindex
        });
    }
    
    private async customLoader(tile: any, sourceUrl: string): Promise<void> {

        const response = await fetch(sourceUrl, {
            method: 'POST',
            credentials: 'include',
            headers: new Headers({
                Authorization: `Bearer ${...}`
            }),
            body: requestBody ? requestBody : null
        });

        const blob = await response.blob();
        tile.getImage().src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    }
}
```

--- 07.19.

I have created a dummy axample (Angular9, Openlayers 6.3.1):
Layers tiles are loading fast. On small screen panning is fast, but on large screen panning is slow (after loading and cacheing tiles). The performance was better in openlayers 5.

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component } from '@angular/core';
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile';
import Map from 'ol/Map';
import { OSM } from 'ol/source';
import View from 'ol/View';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {

        const mapElement = document.createElement('div');
        mapElement.style.cssText = 'position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%';

        const layers = [];

        for (let i = 0; i < 30; ++i) {
            const layer = new TileLayer({
                source: new OSM(),
                // className: 'layer' + i => create own canvas by layers, same performance
            });
            layer.setOpacity(0.03);
            layers.push(layer);
        }

        const map = new Map({
            layers,
            view: new View({
                center: [0, 0],
                zoom: 1
            })
        });

        document.body.appendChild(mapElement);
        map.setTarget(mapElement);
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi Anmap. Welcome to StackOverflow. Please show us code, which you need to optimize. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. It might make it easier to help you.

Comment: Added code tried by user in the question

Comment: Did you ever solve the performance issues? I have the same problem and I'm pretty sure that it comes down to the rendering. Your fix in your answer below does not make it any better for me.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution, not perfect, but the performance is better.

```
map.on('movestart', () => {
    layers.forEach(layer => {
        layer.setExtent(map.getView().calculateExtent());
    });
});

map.on('moveend', () => {
    layers.forEach(layer => {
        layer.setExtent(undefined);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`URL.createObjectURL` can cause memory leaks, try

```
    const blob = await response.blob();
    const objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
    tile.getImage().onload = function(){
      URL.revokeObjectURL(objectURL);
    };
    tile.getImage().src = objectURL;
```

Also do any of your layers use the same WMS URL with a diiferent WMS `layerName`?  It would be more efficient to combine them into a single OpenLayers layer with a list of WMS layer names in the LAYERS parameter.

Comment: I have to change layers visibility by layer:(

Comment: If it is just visibility (not opacity) you could use `layer.getSource().updateParams({LAYERS : newlayerlist});`

Comment: I'am sorry, but not same urls, I can try forking urls by larenames in tileLoadFunction. But, if one of the service is slow, the whole tile loading will be slow, ..., and I have to rendering the tiles.